# How to make a Youden plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am wondering how to create a Youden plot to analyse the results of an inter-laboratory test. Here you can download data: [data](https://my.cloudme.com/josechka/dat_youd). The test consisted on determining the performance of participants to measure 3 levels of one magnitude. The data contains individual means and standard deviations for each participant in each of the levels.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Is it not just a [scatterplot](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html)?

Comment: @zx8754: don't think so ... https://www.medialabinc.net/spg49755/what_is_a_youden_plot.aspx

Comment: To me it still looks like a scatterplot with guide circles and rectangles. Could you please add a weblink to a desired plot?

Answer (score 3):

So, since you do not precise what a Youden plot is, for you, and that I never heard of such a plot before, i'll use [W. J. Youden (1959)](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a077630.pdf#page=143) definition directly to draw it.

> The  graph  is  prepared  by  drawing  the  customary  x-axis  at  the  bottom  of  the  paper  and  laying  off  on  this axis  a  scale that covers  the range  of results for  material A.  At the  left the y-axis  is  provided  with a  scale in the same  units  that  includes  the  range  of  results  reported for  material B.  The  pair  of results  reported  by  a  laboratory  are  then  used  to plot  a  point.  There  will  be  as many  points  as  there  are  reporting  laboratories.  After the points  are plotted  a horizontal  median  line is drawn parallel  to  the  x-axis  so  that  there  are  as many  points above  the  line  as  there  are  below  it.  A  second  median line  is  drawn  parallel  to  the y-axis  and so  placed  that there are  as  many points  on the left as  there  are  on  the right  of  this  line.

Let's start with that.

```r
dat <- read.table("dat_youd.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE)
datL <- split(dat,dat$levels) 
#I don't really get what your levels are and why there are three of them though, but i'll assume there are equivalent to Youden's "materials".
plot(datL[[1]]$MeanValues,datL[[2]]$MeanValues,asp=1, pch=19, xlab="Sample A", ylab="Sample B") 
#asp=1 because of the circle.
mB <- median(datL[[2]]$MeanValues)
mA <- median(datL[[1]]$MeanValues)
abline(h=mB, v=mA)
```

The third element of the plot is the 45° line:

> Assuming that the two materials are similar in type and nearly equal in magnitude for the property the dispersion among the results reported for A should be about the same as the dispersion of the B results. In that event the 45 degree line through the intersection of the medians makes possible an estimate of the precision of the data.

Which is:

```
curve(x-(mA-mB),from=par('usr')[1],to=par('usr')[3],add=TRUE) 
#I use here par('usr') so that it expands on the whole plot area
```

Then the "standard deviation" computation:

> The perpendicular distance from each point to the 45 degree line can be used to form an estimate of the precision. [...] These perpendiculars need not be measured on the graph paper. Instead write for each laboratory the difference A - B keeping track of the signs. Call these differences d1, d2, ..., dn. Calculate d the algebraic average difference. Subtract d from each difference and obtain a set of corrected differences d'1, d'2,..., d'n. The average of the absolute values of these differences multiplied by sqrt(pi)/2 or 0.886 gives an estimate of standard deviation.

Let's calculate that:

```
d <- mean(datL[[1]]$MeanValues-datL[[2]]$MeanValues)
d_prime <- datL[[1]]$MeanValues-datL[[2]]$MeanValues-d
r <- mean(abs(d_prime))*sqrt(pi)/2
```

And finally the circle:

> Multiplying the standard deviation obtained above by 2.45 gives the radius of the circle that should include 95 percent of the laboratories if individual constant errors could be eliminated.

That we can draw the following way:

```
r <- 2.45 * r
t <- seq(0,2*pi,by=0.01)
x <- r*cos(t) + mA
y <- r*sin(t) + mB
lines(x,y)
```

The result:

[image: Youden Plot]

And as a function:

```
youden <- function(serieA, serieB){
    plot(serieA,serieB,asp=1, pch=19, xlab="Sample A", ylab="Sample B") 
    mB <- median(serieB)
    mA <- median(serieA)
    abline(h=mB, v=mA)
    curve(x-(mA-mB),from=par('usr')[1],to=par('usr')[3],add=TRUE)
    d <- mean(serieA-serieB)
    d_prime <- serieA-serieB-d
    r <- 2.45*mean(abs(d_prime))*sqrt(pi)/2
    t<-seq(0,2*pi,by=0.01)
    x<-r*cos(t)+mA
    y<-r*sin(t)+mB
    lines(x,y)
    }
```

Using your third serie as example:

```
youden(datL[[1]]$MeanValues, datL[[3]]$MeanValues)
```

[image]